# Macbook Air macOS high Sierra,128GB, 2013

Tags: macbook-pro

[image][image][image]

I did partition and saw that Windows is being partitioned on main hard drive and I can't delete it. It took the free space. Now I have only 39 GB free space. How can I delete the Windows installation?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it removed the new partition which was created not the old one  ,it is still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this walkthrough on how to remove a windows partition from a mac:
http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/09/remove-windows-boot-camp-partition-mac/

Hopefully this works for you, but let us know if you're still having issues!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Link only answer may not be very helpful as the link are liable to get expired. Consider quoting the linked content as part of the answer